# Как переносить информацию между формами?

Tags: c++, clr

Есть две формы, на первой есть кнопка, по нажатию которой открывается вторая. В ней в несколько textbox вписываются числа. По нажатию кнопки на второй форме, числа, вписанные в textbox, должны передаваться в первую форму, в переменные. Нашел решение посредством создания класса в основной форме, но получаю много ошибок, которые не знаю, как устранить.
Мои попытки реализации:
MyForm (основная):

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>;
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyForm1.h"
#include <string>

namespace kursovaya {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;
/// <summary>
/// Сводка для MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public: string str;
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        str = new string(); 
        str.a = " ";        
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }

protected:



private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox1;
private: Bitmap^ img1;
private: Bitmap^ img2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ checkBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button10;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button11;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label10;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button12;
private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
    /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->checkBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->openFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
        this->saveFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))- 
>BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(32, 174);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(798, 476);
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 4;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(39, 662);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 5;
        this->label1->Text = L"Разимер изображения:";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(437, 662);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(17, 13);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 6;
        this->label2->Text = L"X:";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this->label3->AutoSize = true;
        this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(490, 662);
        this->label3->Name = L"label3";
        this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(17, 13);
        this->label3->TabIndex = 7;
        this->label3->Text = L"Y:";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this->label4->AutoSize = true;
        this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(570, 662);
        this->label4->Name = L"label4";
        this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(18, 13);
        this->label4->TabIndex = 8;
        this->label4->Text = L"R:";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this->label5->AutoSize = true;
        this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(641, 662);
        this->label5->Name = L"label5";
        this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(18, 13);
        this->label5->TabIndex = 9;
        this->label5->Text = L"G:";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this->label6->AutoSize = true;
        this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(706, 662);
        this->label6->Name = L"label6";
        this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(17, 13);
        this->label6->TabIndex = 10;
        this->label6->Text = L"B:";
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this->label7->AutoSize = true;
        this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(360, 662);
        this->label7->Name = L"label7";
        this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(54, 13);
        this->label7->TabIndex = 11;
        this->label7->Text = L"Пиксель:";
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this->checkBox1->AutoSize = true;
        this->checkBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(894, 662);
        this->checkBox1->Name = L"checkBox1";
        this->checkBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(254, 17);
        this->checkBox1->TabIndex = 12;
        this->checkBox1->Text = L"Применить фильтр к половине изображения";
        this->checkBox1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 36);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 13;
        this->button1->Text = L"Открыть";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 66);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 14;
        this->button2->Text = L"Сохранить";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button2_Click);
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 96);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 23);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 15;
        this->button3->Text = L"Восстановить";
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button3->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button3_Click);
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 125);
        this->button4->Name = L"button4";
        this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 23);
        this->button4->TabIndex = 16;
        this->button4->Text = L"Выход";
        this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button4->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button4_Click);
        // 
        // label8
        // 
        this->label8->AutoSize = true;
        this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(42, 13);
        this->label8->Name = L"label8";
        this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 13);
        this->label8->TabIndex = 17;
        this->label8->Text = L"Файл";
        // 
        // label9
        // 
        this->label9->AutoSize = true;
        this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(152, 13);
        this->label9->Name = L"label9";
        this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(76, 13);
        this->label9->TabIndex = 18;
        this->label9->Text = L"Инструменты";
        // 
        // button5
        // 
        this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(155, 29);
        this->button5->Name = L"button5";
        this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button5->TabIndex = 19;
        this->button5->Text = L"Фильтр 1";
        this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button5_Click);
        // 
        // button6
        // 
        this->button6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(155, 58);
        this->button6->Name = L"button6";
        this->button6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button6->TabIndex = 20;
        this->button6->Text = L"Фильтр 2";
        this->button6->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button6->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button6_Click);
        // 
        // button7
        // 
        this->button7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(155, 87);
        this->button7->Name = L"button7";
        this->button7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button7->TabIndex = 21;
        this->button7->Text = L"Фильтр 3";
        this->button7->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button7->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button7_Click);
        // 
        // button8
        // 
        this->button8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(155, 116);
        this->button8->Name = L"button8";
        this->button8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button8->TabIndex = 22;
        this->button8->Text = L"Фильтр 4";
        this->button8->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button8->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button8_Click);
        // 
        // button9
        // 
        this->button9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(155, 145);
        this->button9->Name = L"button9";
        this->button9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button9->TabIndex = 23;
        this->button9->Text = L"Фильтр 5";
        this->button9->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button9->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button9_Click);
        // 
        // button10
        // 
        this->button10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(256, 36);
        this->button10->Name = L"button10";
        this->button10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(134, 23);
        this->button10->TabIndex = 24;
        this->button10->Text = L"Увеличить масштаб";
        this->button10->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button11
        // 
        this->button11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(256, 66);
        this->button11->Name = L"button11";
        this->button11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(134, 23);
        this->button11->TabIndex = 25;
        this->button11->Text = L"Уменьшить масштаб";
        this->button11->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // label10
        // 
        this->label10->AutoSize = true;
        this->label10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(256, 13);
        this->label10->Name = L"label10";
        this->label10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(26, 13);
        this->label10->TabIndex = 26;
        this->label10->Text = L"Вид";
        // 
        // button12
        // 
        this->button12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(417, 36);
        this->button12->Name = L"button12";
        this->button12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button12->TabIndex = 27;
        this->button12->Text = L"Справка";
        this->button12->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // openFileDialog1
        // 
        this->openFileDialog1->FileName = L"openFileDialog1";
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1218, 695);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button12);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label10);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button11);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button10);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"0105_ТасмагамбетовАндрей";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();
        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (openFileDialog1 -> ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
        {
            img1 = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1 -> FileName);
            img2 = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1->FileName);
            pictureBox1 -> Image = img1;
        }
    }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (pictureBox1->Image)
    {
        pictureBox1->Image = img2;
        img1 = img2;
    }
    else
        MessageBox::Show("Ошибка, картинка не загружена");
}
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    exit(0);
}
private: System::Void button6_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (pictureBox1->Image)
    {
        int q1;
        MyForm^ frm2 = gcnew MyForm(str); 
        frm2->ShowDialog();
        q1 = atoi(str);
    }
    else
        MessageBox::Show("Error, picture missing");
}
}
};
}
```

MyForm1 (вторая форма):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyForm.h"

namespace kursovaya {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;
/// <summary>
/// Сводка для MyForm1
/// </summary>
/// 
public ref class MyForm1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private: string str2; // Делаю указатель
public:
    MyForm1(string Astr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        str2 = Astr;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
};
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label5;

private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;




private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
    /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 24);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(151, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"Введите диапазон q1-q2 для";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 92);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(15, 13);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
        this->label2->Text = L"R";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this->label3->AutoSize = true;
        this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 151);
        this->label3->Name = L"label3";
        this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(15, 13);
        this->label3->TabIndex = 2;
        this->label3->Text = L"G";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this->label4->AutoSize = true;
        this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 205);
        this->label4->Name = L"label4";
        this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(14, 13);
        this->label4->TabIndex = 3;
        this->label4->Text = L"B";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this->label5->AutoSize = true;
        this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 252);
        this->label5->Name = L"label5";
        this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(63, 13);
        this->label5->TabIndex = 4;
        this->label5->Text = L"от 1 до 255";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this->label6->AutoSize = true;
        this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(130, 49);
        this->label6->Name = L"label6";
        this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
        this->label6->TabIndex = 6;
        this->label6->Text = L"q1";
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this->label7->AutoSize = true;
        this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(404, 49);
        this->label7->Name = L"label7";
        this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
        this->label7->TabIndex = 7;
        this->label7->Text = L"q2";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 92);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(363, 91);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 143);
        this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
        this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox3->TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // textBox4
        // 
        this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(363, 143);
        this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
        this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox4->TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // textBox5
        // 
        this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 198);
        this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
        this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox5->TabIndex = 12;
        // 
        // textBox6
        // 
        this->textBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(363, 198);
        this->textBox6->Name = L"textBox6";
        this->textBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox6->TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(363, 247);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 14;
        this->button1->Text = L"применить";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(606, 290);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm1";
        this->Text = L"Фильтр 2";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

    }
};

}
```

Comment: Создайте управляемый класс, добавьте туда публичных полей, передавайте ссылку на экземпляр класса между формами. Ну или выделите себе неуправляемой памяти, и по-старинке. А еще лучше, используйте C#, если вам надо писать что-то под CLR, а не просто между делом вызвать какую-нибудь стандартную форму из WinForms. Прямого ответа у меня нет, потому что я не знаю, что означает `но получаю много ошибок`. Ошибок времени компиляции или выполнения? Каких именно ошибок? Много - это сколько?

Comment: Пока складывается ощущение, что вы перепутали `std::string` и `System::String^`.

Comment: @aepot
C# использовать не могу...
ошибки появляются при компиляции, их 19, если важно
в обоих формах, в строках "private: string str;" и "public: string str2;"
появляются аналогичные ошибки: "C4368 не удается определить "str" как член управляемого "kursovaya::MyForm1": смешанные типы не поддерживаются"
и потом, в первой форме в строке "str = new string();" и во второй форме в "str2 = Astr;" появляются аналогичные ошибки "C2678 бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::string" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)"
Думается, отсюда все последующие ошибки

Comment: @aepot
поменял std::string на System::String^, ошибка С4368 была устранена, но после появилось C2440 =: невозможно преобразовать "std::string" в "System::String ^"
как мне следует поменять последующий код?

Comment: Я почти не знаком с плюсами, только на шарпе могу, мне очень сложно читать этот код. Я лишь увидел странность и сказал о ней, как переписать правильно - это не ко мне. :)

Comment: @aepot
жалко, но за наводку спасибо